# I get GL_INVALID_VALUE after calling glTexSubImage2D

Tags: opengl

I am trying to figure out why my texture allocation does not work.  Here is the code:

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGBA8, 2048, 2048);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 2048, 2048, GL_RGB,
                GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5_REV, &BitMap[0]);
```

`glTexSubImage2D` returns `GL_INVALID_VALUE` but the maximum texture allowed is 16384x16384 on my card.

The source of the image is 16bit (Red 5, Green 6, Blue 5).

Comment: haha thanks I messed up reading this one, didn't notice that first block was two lines

Comment: There are [a number of reasons](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml) why `glTexSubImage2D` might return `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. (See the *Errors* section.) Have you checked which one of those it is?

Comment: Yes I looked at this page before posting but none of them seems to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You try to write an RGB image in an RGBA buffer. This is probably what is causing the problem. Since your source image is in RGB format, you should change GL_RGBA to **GL_RGB** at glTexStorage2D.

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGB8, 2048, 2048);
```

Comment: To clarify, RGB8 uses 8 bits each for red,green,blue,alpha, while RGB uses a variable number of bits for each rgb. Also, ["GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if type is one of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_3_3_2, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE_2_3_3_REV, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5_REV and format is not GL_RGB."](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml)

Comment: @AnastasiosG: it's allowed to write RGB data into an RGBA buffer; the driver will do the format conversion.

Comment: I think it's allowed too since all my lower resolutions storage work and display correctly.